# Приостановка программы в java

Tags: java

У меня кнопка сделанная в графическом интерфейсе среды netbeans. В самом коде я прописал, чтобы происходило событие при нажатии кнопки, но как сделать, чтобы программа не шла дальше, пока я не нажму мышкой на эту кнопку?

Comment: Я не совсем понял, вам нужно чтобы основной поток останавливался на каком-то событии, пока вы не нажмете кнопку в самом NB? А не проще ли поставить отметку и использовать режим отладки?

Comment: Что значит "чтобы не шла дальше", что действия программа выполняет?

Answer (score 1):

Если GUI реагирует на ваши действия, например, позволяет нажать кнопку, а не "висит", значит в этот момент программа не выполняет никаких действий, а просто ожидает срабатывания какого-нибудь события.

Но это в том случае, если Вы не создавали другие потоки, в которых параллельно выполняются какие-то действия. В этом случае GUI "висеть" не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Программа и так не идет дальше. Она запускается, выполняет до конца метод main() и ждет нажатия кнопки (или другого действия пользователя).